# How do you remove a certain word from one file that starts with a certain letter put it into a new file?

Tags: java

My assignment is to remove all the occurrences of a certain word from a file.  Using a textfile that has already been created. I am using the pledge of allegiance  Create a new file called filtered.txt with all the words removed that start with a given letter. Ask the user for the letter you want to use.

So I have the pledge of allegiance text:

```
I pledge Allegiance to the flag
of the United States of America
and to the Republic for which it stands,
one nation under God, indivisible,
with Liberty and Justice for all.
```

Then if use the letter "a" it is supposed to be:

```
I pledge to the flag
of the United States of
and to the Republic for which it stands,
one nation under God, indivisible,
with Liberty Justice for.
```

My program does not work when it is an uppercase letter.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
   public class filteredWords{
      public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
         PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("filteredWords.txt"));
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("pledge.txt"));
         System.out.println("What letter would you like to use?");
         char letter = input.next().charAt(0);
         while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            String word= reader.next();
            for(int i = 0; i<=0; i++){
               char ch = word.charAt(i);
               if(ch!=letter){
                  writer.print(word+" ");
                  word=reader.next();
               }
            }
         }
         writer.close();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Your for loop looks suspect:  i<=0  should be i<=word.length(). Also to do case insensitive comparisons you should call toLowerCase() on any Strings that you find.

Answer (score 1):

For chars, 'A' != 'a'.
You can convert the first letter to lower case by using Character.toLowerCase(char) before you do the comparison.